# Which details to be entered in credentials Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

[image]

I am new to the jenkins, which credentials to be entered, when we paste the github or bitbucket URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only clone project from public bitbucker or github repository you don't need pass credential for it. But if you want clone private repository you have to to add new credential. You will have to choose property kind of credential. For example for github you can choose username with password type and enter necessarily data.

Comment: I am confused, we have to use registered username or email

Answer (score 0):

You can use your bitbucket or github credentials. Firstly you have to create the secret for your credentials. Then you'll be able to use that secret in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in global tool configuration "git" path set is correct
2. Ensure the Repository URL path is correct. Follow the following syntax to mention URL
   ex. https://gitlab.com/username/Reponame.git

After mentioning path in source code management copy that and paste in browser window. You should navigate to your repository

3. You have to add credentials in Jenkins. Click on add button next to credentials .
4. Select Jenkins and it will display "Jenkins Credentials Provider: Jenkins" popup
5. From "Kind" drop-down select Username and Password option
6. Enter your username in "Username" text-box and password in "Password" text-box and Click on add button.
7. From credentials drop-down select your username and password combination